# Secure connection between client and server on different domains

Tags: php, javascript

I am doing a module in which i need to handover the pre designed page to a client and when client uses this page it can communicate between my server and client page.
The problem is if I want to access server from other client page I need to give username,pass,host which must be written in the pre designed client page.
How can I make it hide from the client to get the info and securely operate the task.
Is there any approach or Am I wrong somewhere.
I am doing this in php and javascript
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use curl or file_get_contents method to share the file content. In this way you wont need to provide ftp details. But need to implement a SOAP or REST Server type of architecture.

Comment: I dont have any idea about these architectures, Were can i find relative info and implentation examples, or how to create REST or SOAP Architecture.